# Filtering Posts by tags and displaying them underneath instantly

Tags: wordpress, search, filter, tags, instant

On my website I have all kinds of products (gift ideas) and want to make them easier accessible for visitors.

The plan is to build a page called 'present finder', where you can select a ***price range***, the persons ***age*** (kid, teenie or grownup) and ***tags*** referring to their interests (e.g. Design, Nature, Travel, Sports).

It should look something like this:
[Link to how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVvsG.jpg)

I doubt I would have any trouble building the GUI, or tagging all my posts but:

**Question**:

- How do I make it work that as soon as options are changed (like tags
  or price range), the right posts are being displayed underneath
  **instantly**?  I don't want to be forced to install a 'search' button and I dont want the page to reload every time the user adds a
  tag or changes the price range.
- Is there maybe a plugin that does exactly what I need so I don't have to build it from scratch?

I researched for over 40 min and couldn't find anything.

Thanks a lot for your help. Cheers!